# Подскажите с выбором компоненты для рисования

Tags: .net, picturebox

С#, WinForms, Net.4.5.

Задача: рендеринг от 0 до 5000 объектов представленных в виде упорядоченного списка уже адаптированных объектов (линия, эллипс, Безье, кривые и т.д.).

Пытался сделать привязку `panel + picturebox + bitmap` - не вышло из-за размеров изображения (может достигать свыше 10 метров по высоте и ширине). Отказывается работать сразу на создании `Bitmap`. Отказался от `Bitmap`.

Стал рисовать напрямую на `PictureBox`. Работает очень медленно. `SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true )` не спасло. Для работы был создан компонент `Линейка`, она динамическая и привязана к панели, а при прокрутке меняет метрику под изображение на `PictureBox`. Суть в том, что в принципе само изображение которое в сумме получается из всех объектов рендерится нормально, но вот встал вопрос при движении мыши ставить перекрестие 2 прямые линии через всё поле для удобности сличения координат точки… вот тут и начались сильные тормоза (мерцание). Подскажите, может есть что-то для таких целей, или может выбрать что-то кардинально другое?

Всё чтение данных для объектов и сами внутренние расчеты уже оттестированы и удовлетворяют потребности, но вот сторона отображения просто оставляет все надежды.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю лучше попробовать использовать DirectX/OpenGL.

Например для OpenGL можно использовать библиотеку TAO framework.

На практике столкнулся с необходимость отрисовки 3х-мерной диаграммы 10 000 объектов. Стандартные средства жутко тормозили поэтому использовал эту библиотеку

На этом [сайте](http://esate.ru/uroki/OpenGL/uroki-OpenGL-c-sharp/) есть подробное описание как работать с этой библиотекой

Вот пример вывода графика функции с помощью библиотеки TAO framework, нужно добавить входящий в состав библиотеки контрол  на форму.

```
// размеры окна 
double ScreenW, ScreenH; 

// отношения сторон окна визуализации 
// для корректного перевода координат мыши в координаты, 
// принятые в программе 

private float devX; 
private float devY; 

// массив, который будет хранить значения x,y точек графика 
private float[,] GrapValuesArray; 
// количество элементов в массиве 
private int elements_count = 0; 

// флаг, означающий, что массив с значениями координат графика пока еще не заполнен 
private bool not_calculate = true; 

// номер ячейки массива, из которой будут взяты координаты для красной точки 
// для визуализации текущего кадра 
private int pointPosition = 0; 

// вспомогательные переменные для построения линий от курсора мыши к координатным осям 
float lineX, lineY; 

// текущение координаты курсора мыши 
float Mcoord_X = 0, Mcoord_Y = 0; 

public Form1() 
{ 
  InitializeComponent(); 
  AnT.InitializeContexts();
} 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

  // инициализация библиотеки glut 
  Glut.glutInit(); 
  // инициализация режима экрана 
  Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_RGB | Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE); 

  // установка цвета очистки экрана (RGBA) 
  Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1); 

  // установка порта вывода 
  Gl.glViewport(0, 0, AnT.Width, AnT.Height); 

  // активация проекционной матрицы 
  Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION); 
  // очистка матрицы 
  Gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

  // определение параметров настройки проекции в зависимости от размеров сторон элемента AnT. 
  if ((float)AnT.Width <= (float)AnT.Height) 
  { 
    ScreenW = 30.0; 
    ScreenH = 30.0 * (float)AnT.Height / (float)AnT.Width; 
    Glu.gluOrtho2D(0.0, ScreenW, 0.0, ScreenH);
  } 
  else 
  {
    ScreenW = 30.0 * (float)AnT.Width / (float)AnT.Height; 
    ScreenH = 30.0; 
    Glu.gluOrtho2D(0.0, 30.0 * (float)AnT.Width / (float)AnT.Height, 0.0, 30.0);
  } 

  // сохранение коэффициентов, которые нам необходимы для перевода координат указателя в оконной системе в координаты, 
  // принятые в нашей OpenGL сцене 
  devX = (float)ScreenW / (float)AnT.Width; 
  devY = (float)ScreenH / (float)AnT.Height; 

  // установка объектно-видовой матрицы 
  Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW); 

  // старт счетчика, отвечающего за вызов функции визуализации сцены 
  PointInGrap.Start();

} 

// функция обработчик события таймера 
private void PointInGrap_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

  // если мы дошли до последнего элемента массива 
  if (pointPosition == elements_count-1) 
    pointPosition = 0; // переходим к начальному элементу 

  // функция визуализации 
  Draw(); 

  // переход к следующему элементу массива 
  pointPosition++;

} 

// обработка движения мыши над элементом AnT 
private void AnT_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 

// сохраняем координаты мыши 
Mcoord_X = e.X; 
Mcoord_Y = e.Y; 

// вычисляем параметры для будущей дорисовки линий от указателя мыши к координатным осям. 
lineX = devX * e.X; 
lineY = (float)(ScreenH - devY * e.Y);

} 

// функция визуализации текста 
private void PrintText2D(float x, float y, string text) 
{ 

  // устанавливаем позицию вывода растровых символов 
  // в переданных координатах x и y. 
  Gl.glRasterPos2f(x, y); 

  // в цикле foreach перебираем значения из массива text, 
  // который содержит значение строки для визуализации 
  foreach (char char_for_draw in text) 
  { 
    // символ C визуализируем с помощью функции glutBitmapCharacter, используя шрифт GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15. 
    Glut.glutBitmapCharacter(Glut.GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, char_for_draw);
  }

} 

// функция, производящая вычисления координат графика 
// и заносящая их в массив GrapValuesArray 
private void functionCalculation() 
{ 

  // определение локальных переменных X и Y 
  float x = 0, y = 0; 

  // инициализация массива, который будет хранить значение 300 точек, 
  // из которых будет состоять график 

  GrapValuesArray = new float[300, 2]; 

  // счетчик элементов массива 
  elements_count = 0; 

  // вычисления всех значений y для x, принадлежащего промежутку от -15 до 15 с шагом в 0.01f 
  for (x = -15; x < 15; x += 0.1f) 
  { 
    // вычисление y для текущего x 
    // по формуле y = (float)Math.Sin(x)*3 + 1; 
    // эта строка задает формулу, описывающую график функции для нашего уравнения y = f(x). 
    y = (float)Math.Sin(x)*3 + 1; 

    // запись координаты x 
    GrapValuesArray[elements_count, 0] = x; 
    // запись координаты y 
    GrapValuesArray[elements_count, 1] = y; 
    // подсчет элементов 
    elements_count++;

  } 

  // изменяем флаг, сигнализировавший о том, что координаты графика не вычислены 
  not_calculate = false;

} 
// визуализация графика 
private void DrawDiagram() 
{ 

  // проверка флага, сигнализирующего о том, что координаты графика вычислены 
  if (not_calculate) 
  { 
    // если нет, то вызываем функцию вычисления координат графика 
    functionCalculation();
  } 

  // стартуем отрисовку в режиме визуализации точек 
  // объединяемых в линии (GL_LINE_STRIP) 
  Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINE_STRIP); 

  // рисуем начальную точку 
  Gl.glVertex2d(GrapValuesArray[0, 0], GrapValuesArray[0, 1]); 

  // проходим по массиву с координатами вычисленных точек 
  for (int ax = 1; ax < elements_count; ax+=2) 
  { 
    // передаем в OpenGL информацию о вершине, участвующей в построении линий 
    Gl.glVertex2d(GrapValuesArray[ax, 0], GrapValuesArray[ax, 1]);
  } 

  // завершаем режим рисования 
  Gl.glEnd(); 

  // устанавливаем размер точек, равный 5 пикселям 
  Gl.glPointSize(5); 
  // устанавливаем текущим цветом - красный цвет 
  Gl.glColor3f(255, 0, 0); 
  // активируем режим вывода точек (GL_POINTS) 
  Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POINTS); 
  // выводим красную точку, используя ту ячейку массива, до которой мы дошли (вычисляется в функции обработчике событий таймера) 
  Gl.glVertex2d(GrapValuesArray[pointPosition, 0], GrapValuesArray[pointPosition, 1]); 
  // завершаем режим рисования 
  Gl.glEnd(); 
  // устанавливаем размер точек равный единице 
  Gl.glPointSize(1);

} 

// функция, управляющая визуализацией сцены 
private void Draw() 
{ 

  // очистка буфера цвета и буфера глубины 
  Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

  // очищение текущей матрицы 
  Gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

  // установка черного цвета 
  Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0); 

  // помещаем состояние матрицы в стек матриц 
  Gl.glPushMatrix(); 

  // выполняем перемещение в пространстве по осям X и Y 
  Gl.glTranslated(15, 15, 0); 

  // активируем режим рисования (Указанные далее точки будут выводиться как точки GL_POINTS) 
  Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POINTS); 

  // с помощью прохода вдумя циклами, создаем сетку из точек 
  for (int ax = -15; ax < 15; ax++) 
  {
    for (int bx = -15; bx < 15; bx++) 
    { 
      // вывод точки 
      Gl.glVertex2d(ax, bx);
    } 
  } 

  // завершение режима рисования примитивов 
  Gl.glEnd(); 

  // активируем режим рисования, каждые 2 последовательно вызванные команды glVertex 
  // объединяются в линии 
  Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES); 

  // далее мы рисуем координатные оси и стрелки на их концах 
  Gl.glVertex2d(0, -15); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(0, 15); 

  Gl.glVertex2d(-15, 0); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(15, 0); 

  // вертикальная стрелка 
  Gl.glVertex2d(0, 15); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(0.1, 14.5); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(0, 15); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(-0.1, 14.5); 

  // горизонтальная трелка 
  Gl.glVertex2d(15, 0); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(14.5, 0.1); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(15, 0); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(14.5, -0.1); 

  // завершаем режим рисования 
  Gl.glEnd(); 

  // выводим подписи осей "x" и "y" 
  PrintText2D(15.5f, 0, "x"); 
  PrintText2D(0.5f, 14.5f, "y"); 

  // вызываем функцию рисования графика 
  DrawDiagram(); 

  // возвращаем матрицу из стека 
  Gl.glPopMatrix(); 

  // выводим текст со значением координат возле курсора 
  PrintText2D(devX * Mcoord_X + 0.2f, (float)ScreenH - devY * Mcoord_Y + 0.4f, "[ x: " + (devX * Mcoord_X - 15).ToString() + " ; y: " + ((float)ScreenH - devY * Mcoord_Y - 15).ToString() + "]"); 

  // устанавливаем красный цвет 
  Gl.glColor3f(255, 0, 0); 

  // включаем режим рисования линий, для того чтобы нарисовать 
  // линии от курсора мыши к координатным осям 
  Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES); 

  Gl.glVertex2d(lineX, 15); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(lineX, lineY); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(15, lineY); 
  Gl.glVertex2d(lineX, lineY); 

  Gl.glEnd(); 

  // дожидаемся завершения визуализации кадра 
  Gl.glFlush(); 

  // сигнал для обновление элемента реализующего визуализацию. 
  AnT.Invalidate();

}
```

Comment: поддерживаю OpenGL. На Java отказался от встроенных библиотек рисования, потому что при 10к графиках все тормозило, ушел в сторону OpenGL для нагрузки на видеокарту.

Comment: Вот уже тоже к этому варианту смотрю в сторону, только вот вопрос по реализации, так сказать по результату, а Можно ли получить от Тао такого результата, сама форма уже с тулзами вокруг и с 75% всего математического и т.д. готово, мне как бы требуется в виде контрола установить на форму и сменить методы рендеринга всего проекта ??? такое возможно ? или придётся все приложение переписывать

Comment: Трудно сказать, я не знаком с вашим проектом. Но в качестве контекста рисования там используется специальный контрол, который работает как PictureBox

Comment: Скажем так, в облегченном варианте представте MsPaint с 1000+ объектов которые имеют свои свойства свои матрицы преобразования историю и т.д. но данные хранятся исключительно PointF разное количество в зависимости от типа объекта и всё же это 2Д графика, векторы.

Comment: если не сложно , не могли бы вы дать уточненную информацию что бы не начать в выходные размытое изучение всех возможностей, а сразу начать с нужного, я про аналог PictureBox и есть ли там стандартные возможности задания ед.изм типа mm, pt, px и т.д. вывод линий кривых бизье ?

Comment: Нужно "курить" OpenGL. Еще раз дублирую ссылку на уроки http://esate.ru/uroki/OpenGL/uroki-OpenGL-c-sharp/

Comment: @AlexsandrTer Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.